AttributeError when Using LangChain Google GenerativeAI in a CrewAI Environment
I'm encountering an AttributeError when trying to use LangChain Google GenerativeAI within a CrewAI environment. The error occurs when executing the kickoff() method of the Crew instance. The specific error message points to the langchain_google_genai module, mentioning an AttributeError related to the absence of the '_system_instruction' attribute in the GenerativeModel object.
import os
from langchain_google_genai import ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
from crewai import Agent, Task, Crew, Process

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Load the google gemini api key
    google_api_key = os.getenv("my key")

    # Set gemini pro as llm
    llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(
        model="gemini-pro", verbose=True, temperature=0.9, google_api_key=google_api_key
    )

    # Create agents
    screenwriter = Agent(
        role="Screenwriter",
        goal="Translate ideas into engaging scenes with vivid descriptions, snappy dialogue, and emotional depth.",
        backstory="""Former freelance screenwriter for low-budget indie films. Learned to work quickly under constraints, 
                    generating multiple variations on a theme. Excels at building tension and incorporating plot twists.""",
        verbose=True,
        allow_delegation=False,
        llm=llm,
    )

    critic = Agent(
        role="Analytical Eye & Genre Enforcer",
        goal="Ensure stories are internally consistent, adhere to the intended genre, and maintain stylistic choices.",
        backstory="""A retired film studies professor with an encyclopedic knowledge of classic tropes, storytelling structures, 
                    and audience expectations. Has a knack for spotting potential plot holes and continuity errors.""",
        verbose=True,
        allow_delegation=False,
        llm=llm,
    )

    story_master = Agent(
        role="Project Lead & Master Orchestrator",
        goal="Guide the overall story generation process, manage the workflow between the Screenwriter and Critic, and ensure a cohesive final product.",
        backstory="""A seasoned novelist turned game narrative designer. Has a strong understanding of both high-level plot frameworks and the detailed 
                    scene creation required to immerse a reader in the world.""",
        verbose=True,
        allow_delegation=True,
        llm=llm,
    )

    # Get the story idea from the user
    user_input = input(
        "Please provide a short story idea. You can specify the genre and theme: "
    )

    # Create the task
    story_task = Task(
    description=f"Write a short story with the following user input: {user_input}",
    agent=story_master,
    expected_output="A short story based on the user input."
)

    # Create the crew
    story_crew = Crew(
        agents=[screenwriter, critic, story_master],
        tasks=[story_task],
        verbose=True,
        process=Process.sequential,
    )

    # Execution Flow
    story_output = story_crew.kickoff()


And here is the error i got :-
Please provide a short story idea. You can specify the genre and theme: love
 [DEBUG]: == Working Agent: Project Lead & Master Orchestrator
 [INFO]: == Starting Task: Write a short story with the following user input: love


> Entering new CrewAgentExecutor chain...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-6af00a09bffb> in <cell line: 5>()
     65 
     66     # Execution Flow
---> 67     story_output = story_crew.kickoff()

22 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_google_genai/chat_models.py in _prepare_chat(self, messages, stop, **kwargs)
    647         )
    648         message = history.pop()
--> 649         if self.client._system_instruction != system_instruction:
    650             self.client = genai.GenerativeModel(
    651                 model_name=self.model, system_instruction=system_instruction

AttributeError: 'GenerativeModel' object has no attribute '_system_instruction'



i ran your code in colab and it worked fine

no bro its not working for me

Yes sis it definably working for me.  try and restart your colab sweet heart.

Got the same error, I was working on colab so re-connected the instance and ran the code again, it worked.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
